# show (or disprove) that numbers with at most two prime factors can be expressed as a sum of two squares in at most 2 ways

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math, divisibility, sums-of-squares

> Show (or disprove) that numbers with at most two prime factors can be expressed as a sum of two squares in at most 2 ways.

> This post is inspired by an answer to [this other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4599648/find-the-smallest-positive-integer-that-can-be-written-as-a-sum-of-two-squares-i), say post A.

I found [a post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/719700/if-a-prime-can-be-expressed-as-sum-of-square-of-two-integers-then-prove-that-th), say post B, that proves that if n is prime, then it can be expressed as a sum of two squares in at most one way.  I thought I could modify this proof to show that numbers that have at most two (not necessarily distinct) primes in their prime factorization could be expressed as a sum of two squares in at most one way. The answer in post A uses some useful number theory facts: if $p\equiv 3\mod 4$ is a prime, then it cannot be expressed as a sum of two squares, which is a simple corollary of Fermat's little theorem.

> Now one can prove that if $p$ is a prime, then $p^2$ can be expressed as a sum of two squares in at most two nontrivial ways as shown below.

(start of proof)

Fix any prime number $p$. If $p=2,$ then $4$ can only be written as a sum of two squares in one trivial way: $4 = 0+2^2$. Assume henceforth that p is odd. Note that if $p\equiv 3\mod 4$, then any nontrivial sum $x^2 + y^2$ equal to $p^2$ must satisfy that $x$ and $y$ are coprime. Any positive integers $x,y$ satisfying $x^2+y^2 = p^2$ thus form a primitive Pythagorean triple $(x,y,p)$. But then $p$ is the sum of two squares by the formula for primitive Pythagorean triples, a contradiction. Assume now that $p\equiv 1\mod 4$. Then if $x,y$ are positive integers so that $x^2 + y^2 = p^2,$ we know that $x$ and $y$ are coprime, so $p$ is a sum of two squares. But by the answer in post B, p can be uniquely expressed as a sum of two squares. Hence $p^2$ can be expressed as a sum of two squares of positive integers in at most one way (we consider swapping the order of the two terms or swapping signs the same way).

(end of proof)

> **Question**: Now I'm not sure how to show that if $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, then  $pq$ can be expressed as the sum of two squares in at most two different ways. Clearly, since $pq$ is not a square, both integers must be nonzero, and by flipping signs if necessary, we may assume both integers are positive.

Suppose $$pq= a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + d^2=e^2 + f^2\quad (1)$$. We will prove that not all these three ways of writing pq as a sum of two squares are distinct.  Now note that $a$ and $b$ are coprime, for if they shared a prime factor $t$, then $t^2$ would divide $pq$, which is impossible. We also have $(pq)^2 = (a^2 + b^2)(c^2+d^2) = a^2c^2+a^2d^2+b^2c^2+b^2d^2.$ We see that $$(pq)^2 = (ac+bd)^2 + (ad-bc)^2\quad (2)$$ and $$ (pq)^2= (ac-bd)^2 + (ad+bc)^2\quad (3)$$. Similarly, $(pq)^2 = (ae + bf)^2 + (af-be)^2 = (ae-bf^2)+(af+be)^2 = (ce + df)^2 + (cf-de)^2 = (ce-df)^2 + (cf+de)^2.$ By (1), $$(pq-a^2)d^2 = (pq-c^2)b^2\Rightarrow pq(d^2-b^2) = (ad-bc)(ad+bc)\quad (4).$$ Now $pq | (ad - bc)$ or $pq | (ad + bc)$. If the former occurs, then by $(2),$ $ad-bc = 0$ and so $a=c,b=d$ since $a,b,c,d$ are coprime and if $a | c,b|d, a < c$ or $b<d,$ then $p=a^2 + b^2 < c^2+d^2 = p,$ a contradiction. If the latter occurs, then by (3), $ac-bd = 0\Rightarrow a=d,b=c.$

> Now the harder case is when $p | (ad-bc)$ and $q | (ad+bc)$ or vice versa. Obviously by relabelling we may assume the former occurs. Then we may write $ad-bc = kp$ for some integer k and we have $p^2(q^2 -k^2) = (ac+bd)^2.$ So $ac+bd$ is also divisible by p. I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

> I'm looking for an elementary answer that avoids any use of Algebraic Number Theory concepts to an extent that would no longer be considered elementary.

Comment: In your proof for $p^2$ when $p\equiv1\bmod4,$ knowing that $p$ can be uniquely expressed as a sum of two squares, how do you derive that $p^2$ can be expressed as a sum of two squares of positive integers in (essentially) at most one way?

Comment: Would considering factorisations in $\Bbb Z[i]$ be non-elementary for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was [Euler's argument](https://scholarlycommons.pacific.edu/euler-works/228/) in one of his letters to Goldbach, as transcribed on the French Wikipédia: [Théorème des deux carrés de Fermat, § Euler et la descente infinie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_des_deux_carr%C3%A9s_de_Fermat#Euler_et_la_descente_infinie).

Let $pq=a^2+b^2$ where $p,q$ are distinct primes, hence both (uniquely) sums of two (coprime) squares. Given the decomposition $p=c^2+d^2,$ let us prove that there are (essentialy) only two possibilities for $(a,b).$

Since $pqc^2-a^2p=b^2c^2-a^2d^2,$ we have $p\mid bc+ad$ (wlog, i.e. up to changing $d$ to $-d$ if necessary). Define
$$m:=\frac{bc+ad}p,\quad x:=b-mc,\quad y:=a-md.$$

$mp=bc+ad=(x+mc)c+(y+md)d=mp+xc+yd$ hence $xc+yd=0.$ Since $c,d$ are coprime, $x=nd$ and $y=-nc$ for some integer $n,$ i.e.
$$a=md-nc,\quad b=mc+nd,$$
so that
$$pq=(md-nc)^2+(mc+nd)^2=(m^2+n^2)(c^2+d^2)=(m^2+n^2)p.$$
Therefore, $n$ is uniquely determined up to sign, which ends the proof.

Comment: Thanks. Could you look at [this Dyck path problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4600904/show-that-all-n1-cyclic-shifts-of-an-augmented-dyck-path-are-distinct) if you have time?

Comment: ? I have time but no taste for that very different subject. Btw you didn't answer my question above.